# ROR - Database seed won't give me correct dates - always 1/1/2000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my database with dates/time. When I  run db:seed, I can change the time, but the date is always 1/1/2000
Here's my db/seeds

```
Airport.create!(code: 'ORD')
Airport.create!(code: 'LAX')
Airport.create!(code: 'SFO')
Airport.create!(code: 'NYC')

Flight.create!(arrival_airport_id: 1, departure_airport_id: 2, 
               departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 8, 29, 12, 30, 0), duration: 4.hours)
Flight.create!(arrival_airport_id: 1, departure_airport_id: 3, 
               departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 8, 31, 12, 30, 0), duration: 4.hours)
Flight.create!(arrival_airport_id: 1, departure_airport_id: 4, 
               departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 9, 5, 12, 30, 0), duration: 2.hours)
Flight.create!(arrival_airport_id: 2, departure_airport_id: 1, 
               departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 8, 29, 12, 45, 0), duration: 4.hours)
```

And when I run rails console:
`Flight.first.departure_time` : `Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:30:00 UTC +00:00`

Comment: Yes. I use db:reset, which clears it and reruns seeds.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output I can say that the column `departure_time` is not a `datetime` type column. It's a `time` type column. That's why only the time part is updating.

You can change the column type from `time` to `datetime` by a migration.

```
change_column :flights, :departure_time, :datetime
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks!
How could you tell from my output?